# Strange behaviour of Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I was trying to add a new node to the database tree from my code. It worked perfectly, I didn't change my code. Now when I check the console the node wasn't added but the stragest thing about it that I can still get new added data. I just cannot see in the console. Has it happened to someone else? After 5 mins it added a new node.

Comment: The only time I see the database console missing updates is when I leave it open for a long time (days) and it loses its authentication state. In that case, reloading the page fixes it, but until I realize that it can be confusing. Not sure if that's your case, but it's the best I can do without knowing how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Now it is working perfectly. I dont understand it may the case you were talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your FB console is in "non-realtime mode"? Check if you see a message in the console that says "Read-only & non-realtime mode activated to improve browser performance" (happens when there are too many entries in your DB tree below your current location so the UI does not display the DB entries in realtime anymore).

[image: Firebase Console non-realtime mode]

Comment: Where can I find it in the console? now its working perfectly even I didnt change anything.

Comment: If it's there you can't miss it, right there in the the middle of the screen. Maybe you experienced some Firebase UI glitch, I guess that could happen.

Comment: It wasnt there. It might have been something else